# how to install VMware vSphere Client on centos 6.5

Tags: ssh, centos

How can I install "VMware vSphere Client" on CentOS 6.5?

Comment: Are you talking about the actual client or the VMware tools? If it's the actual client what's the error you're running into?

Comment: I don't know a product called that. Do you mean "vSphere Web Client SDK 5.x"?

Comment: "VMware vSphere Client" is being deprecated in favor of vSphere Web Client. Where is any special need on using the old Client?

Answer (score 2):

According to this [web page](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1006095) vSphere Client is available only for Windows.

The web page gives options on how to use vSphere Web client on Linux.

Comment: The vSphere Web Client uses flash though. Just though I'd mention that.